# EF using Wrong String.Concat

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, linq, entity-framework

I've seen a lot of posts here about String.Concat usage failing; EF documentation says it does support concat, but only the following three overloads:

```
System.String Concat(String str0, String str1)
System.String Concat(String str0, String str1, String str2)
System.String Concat(String str0, String str1, String str2, String str03)
```

The problem I'm having is that VB LINQ is defaulting to using the

```
System.String Concat(ParamArray values As String())
```

overload by default, so I get an error.  Is there a way to force which overload I want within the EF query in VB?  My query I use is the following:

```
from x in table
group join y ...
.
.
select New With { .Text = String.Concat(SqlFunctions.Convert(x.ID), " - ", if (y is null, "", y.Name)) }
```

Even using a select of:

```
select New With { .Text = String.Concat(SqlFunctions.Convert(x.ID), " - ", "TEST NAME") }
```

Fails too, because it uses the array overload, and not the argument overload.  Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: It's usually dictated by the parameters, not sure why it's being forced to use the open parameter array one.

Comment: If I also use `String.Concat("A", "B", "C")` it also fails, saying it used the paramarray version, even though the VS designer shows the version with 3 string args that's listed above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using named parameters

```
select New With { .Text = String.Concat(str0:=SqlFunctions.Convert(x.ID), str1:=" - ", str2:="TEST NAME") }
```